# 2D Collision Detection

Tags: java, 2d, collision-detection

I'm creating a tile-based 2D Game in Java. Everything was fine, but I got stuck in Collision Detection. I tried this method for up collision:

```
public boolean getCollision(Entity en) {
    try {
        Rectangle i = new Rectangle(en.x, en.y, en.width, en.height);
        for (int y = 0; y < image.getHeight(); y++) {
            for (int x = 0; x < image.getWidth(); x++) {
                if (rect[x][y] != null && tile[x][y] != null && rect[x][y].intersects(i))
                    return true;
            }
        }
    } catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
    }
    return false;
}
```

It worked, but the player gets stuck. How can I fix it?

**Code details**:

`rect` is a `java.awt.Rectangle[][]` that represents invisible rectangles based on the tiles. It is initialized like:

```
 for (int y = 0; y < myLevelHeight; y++) {
    for (int x = 0; x < myLevelWidth; x++) {
        if (rect[x][y] == null)
            rect[x][y] = new Rectangle(x * myGameTileSize, y * myGameTileSize, myGameTileSize, myGameTileSize);
    }
}
```

`Entity` **class** just holds the x and the y coordinate, width and height, of an entity.

`image.getWidth()` and `image.getHeight()` are the tile-level width/height.

Can anyone fix this collision, and create the down, left and right or create one method for that?

EDIT: A MCVE, I tried to decrease the code has much I could, but you should get the idea.

```
    package com.game.lost;

import java.awt.Canvas;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Point;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.awt.image.BufferStrategy;

import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class Demo extends Canvas implements Runnable {

    public int tileSize = 16;
    public static final int width = 400, height = 400;
    public JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    public int levelWidth = width / tileSize + 1, levelHeight = height / tileSize + 1;
    public Color[][] tiles = new Color[levelWidth][levelHeight];
    public Rectangle[][] rect = new Rectangle[levelWidth][levelHeight];
    private Thread thread;
    private boolean running = false;
    private int x = tileSize * 10, y = tileSize * 10;
    private boolean up, down = true, left, right;

    public void genLevel() {
        tiles[10][20] = new Color(0, 0, 0);
        tiles[0][19] = new Color(0, 0, 0);
    }

    public void update() {
        for (int y = 0; y < levelHeight; y++) {
            for (int x = 0; x < levelWidth; x++) {
                if (rect[x][y] == null)
                    rect[x][y] = new Rectangle(x * tileSize, y * tileSize, tileSize, tileSize);
                else if (rect[x][y] != null)
                    rect[x][y].setBounds(x * tileSize, y * tileSize, tileSize, tileSize);
            }
        }

        if (!getDownCollision() && down)
            y += 2;
        else if (getDownCollision() || up) {
            up = true;

            if (!getLeftCollision())
                x -= 2;
            else {
                up = false;
                tiles[0][19] = new Color(255, 0, 0);
            }

            tiles[10][20] = new Color(255, 0, 0);
            down = false;
        }
    }

    public void render() {
        BufferStrategy bs = getBufferStrategy();
        if (bs == null) {
            createBufferStrategy(2);
            return;
        }
        Graphics g = bs.getDrawGraphics();
        g.setColor(Color.white);
        g.fillRect(0, 0, width, height);

        g.setColor(Color.red);
        g.fillRect(x, y, tileSize, tileSize);

        for (int y = 0; y < tiles[0].length; y++) {
            for (int x = 0; x < tiles.length; x++) {
                if (tiles[x][y] != null) {
                    g.setColor(tiles[x][y]);
                    g.fillRect(rect[x][y].x, rect[x][y].y, rect[x][y].width, rect[x][y].height);
                }
            }
        }

        g.dispose();
        bs.show();
    }

    public void start() {
        genLevel();
        running = true;
        thread = new Thread(this);
        thread.start();
    }

    public void run() {
        while (running) {
            update();
            render();

            try {
                Thread.sleep(20);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    public boolean getUpCollision() {
        try {
            Point p1 = new Point(x, y);
            for (int y = 0; y < levelHeight; y++) {
                for (int x = 0; x < levelWidth; x++) {
                    if (rect[x][y - 1] != null && tiles[x][y - 1] != null && rect[x][y - 1].contains(p1))
                        return true;
                }
            }
        } catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
        }
        return false;
    }

    public boolean getDownCollision() {
        try {
            Point p1 = new Point(x, y + tileSize);
            for (int y = 0; y < levelHeight; y++) {
                for (int x = 0; x < levelWidth; x++) {
                    if (rect[x][y + 1] != null && tiles[x][y + 1] != null && rect[x][y + 1].contains(p1))
                        return true;
                }
            }
        } catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
        }
        return false;
    }

    public boolean getLeftCollision() {
        try {
            Point p1 = new Point(x, y);
            for (int y = 0; y < levelHeight; y++) {
                for (int x = 0; x < levelWidth; x++) {
                    if (rect[x][y - 1] != null && tiles[x][y - 1] != null && rect[x][y - 1].contains(p1))
                        return true;
                }
            }
        } catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
        }
        return false;
    }

    public boolean getRightCollision() {
        try {
            Point p1 = new Point(x + tileSize, y);
            for (int y = 0; y < levelHeight; y++) {
                for (int x = 0; x < levelWidth; x++) {
                    if (rect[x][y + 1] != null && tiles[x][y + 1] != null && rect[x][y + 1].contains(p1))
                        return true;
                }
            }
        } catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
        }
        return false;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Demo demo = new Demo();

        demo.frame.setResizable(false);
        demo.frame.add(demo);
        demo.frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        demo.frame.setSize(width, height);
        demo.frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        demo.frame.setTitle("Demo");
        demo.frame.setVisible(true);

        demo.start();
    }
}
```

PS: I think that these informations are what you need to create collision, but
**if you need more information to create the collision please ask in the comments**.

**Thanks**

Comment: A short, runnable example which replicates your issue would be easier to diagnose

Comment: Yes, I know, but creating a MCVE of a game with collision, a player and a tile-level would be too complicated to understand the whole code. But, if you want I can post one.

Comment: I'd simply focus on create a series of test data that should and shouldn't meet your requires tons that could be used by your collision method. It doesn't need to run the whole program, just the part that's giving you trouble

Comment: Yes, this is a good idea. I'll create it now and post. Thanks.

Comment: I posted a MCVE. Now, please see if you can answer.

Comment: Based on your example, I'd check to see what the `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` is printing....`y - 1` doesn't look good

Comment: I updated the code. Now the collision is working. But, just in the MCVE. I'll try again in the main code. Thanks for now.

Comment: Why do the left collision in the MCVE doesn't work?